# I have create T3 stack project, I'm trying to setup next JS middleware but It won't triggering

Tags: javascript, next.js, middleware

In my T3 stack app, next js middleware is not triggering,

I have created `middelware.ts` file in root directory.

`middleware.ts`

```
// middleware.ts
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";
import type { NextRequest } from "next/server";

// This function can be marked `async` if using `await` inside
export function middleware(request: NextRequest) {
  console.log("middleware calling");
  return NextResponse.redirect(new URL("/login/:path*", request.url));
}

// See "Matching Paths" below to learn more
export const config = {
  matcher: ["/products/:path*", "/login/:path*"],
};
```

I haven't seen any redirection or console log,
Anyone know why this is happning?

Thanks!

I have referred Next js Docs and some medium docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the fix,
It's just that I have renamed `middleware.ts` to `middleware.page.ts`